# Easy valuation, but

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Let $P$ be an irreducible polynomial of $\mathbb F_q[T]$. Does it exist $s\in\mathbb N_0$ and $s+1$ polynomials $A_i(T)$ in $\mathbb F_q[T]$ not all zero such that $\lim_{n\to+\infty}v_P\left(\sum_{i=0}^sA_i(T)(T^{q^n}-T)^i\right)=+\infty$?
The case $\deg(P)=1$ is obviously true.
Thanks in advance

The context: None of the series $\sum_{n\ge0}\frac1{(T^{q^n}-T)^i}$ ($i\in\mathbb N_0$) converges in $\mathbb F_q(T)_P$, the $P$-adic completion of $\mathbb F_q(T)$. So I wondered whether I could do a finite non-zero linear combinaison of these series such that the resulting series converges.

Comment: Could you give some more context? As written, $s$ has nothing to do with $n$, so just take $A_i(T) = 0$ for $i = 0, \ldots, s$ and the result is trivially true, so there is no content is merely wanting an example.  If you are trying to *do* something with such a set-up, it might be better to focus a question on that.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to say all not the $A_i$'s can be zero. I edit my question.

Comment: What is $\mathbf N_0$: integers that are $\geq 0$?  I don't see any point in allowing $s = 0$, so surely you want $s \geq 1$.  The context you added doesn't explain the point of your question.  The context is a series running over $n$ while the question is a series running over $i$ (with a limit in $n$). Is there a typo in your initial question?

Comment: A reason the series $\sum_{n \geq 0} 1/(T^{q^n}-T)^i$ for $i \geq 1$ (it is pointless to even consider $i = 0$, as all terms in the series are then $1$) does not converge $P$-adically for an irreducible $P$ is that $T^{q^n}-T$ is divisible by $P$ when $n$ is divisible by $\deg P$, so $(T^{q^n}-T)^i$ is divisible by $P^i$ when $n$ is divisible by $\deg P$. Therefore lots of terms in the series from your context paragraph are not $P$-adically integral. I don't see the motivation for seeking a "finite nonzero linear combination" that makes the series converge.